# how to remove one-to-many child from parent given the child id in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I've got

```
class Parent
{
    IList<Child> Children;
}

class Child
{
}
```

When deleting a `Child` I need to remove all references to it from any `Parents` that reference it.

How can I do this in NHibernate?

There is no `Parent` `FK` on `Child`, the relationship is stored in a 3rd "link" table

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a parent-child relation. Children have only one parent (the belong to the parent). This is a many-to-many relation between independent entities. This is a important difference.

You can't actually remove the "children" from the "parent" directly in HQL the way it is designed now. This are your options:

- load the "parents" into memory and remove the "child" from the list.
- Add a reference from the "child" back to the "parents". Make the other relation inverse. It should actually automatically remove the item in the link table when you remove a "child", because the link would belong to the "child" then.
- Delete the link using native SQL. This is not nice, but also not too bad because it is trivial standard sql.

Comment: yeah i realise its a mant-to-many, was being daft. Ive added a property to `Child` but simply made it private to enable deletes to automatically tidy themselves up without exposing the collection

Answer (score 1):

To make this happen, there needs to be a relationship of some sort, starting from the Child Entity.

Then you can simply use cascade-delete to its 3d (I'm guessing this is a many-to-many) table.

Comment: ah youre right, it is a man-to-many. doh! is there a way to do it without having the relationship mapped on the child end? having it there doesnt make sense in my domain. i guess i could make it private but it feels like a hack

Comment: It seems like it does make sense in your domain, since you need an action to happen on its delete... I would simply add it to the mappings. If you really don't want to do that, maybe you can set the cascades on your FK in the DB...